# adding a reduce_with_index iterator to ruby

Tags: ruby

I am using ActiveRecord. It has a handy method called group_by. When I use it with my activerecord objects, i get the below hash:

```
{["junior"]=>[#<Lead id: 1, created_at: "2015-02-13 02:34:39", updated_at: "2015-02-13 02:35:27", case_enabled: true>, #<Lead id: 2, created_at: "2015-02-13 20:48:19", updated_at: "2015-02-13 20:48:19", case_enabled: nil>, ["senior"]=>[#<Lead id: 3, created_at: "2015-02-13 20:48:19", updated_at: "2015-02-13 20:48:19", case_enabled: nil>, #<Lead id: 4, created_at: "2015-02-13 20:49:16", updated_at: "2015-02-13 20:49:16", case_enabled: nil>]}
```

However, I want a hash with subhashes that contain the collection as an ActiveRecord::Relation and column data. So this is what I come up with:

```
i = 0
r = group.reduce({}) do |acc, (k,v)|
  h = {}
  active_record_relation = where(id: v.map(&:id))
  h["#{k.first}_collection"] = active_record_relation
  h["#{k.first}_columns"] = Classification.where(code: k.first).first.default_fields
  acc[i] = h
  i += 1
  acc
end
```

And it gives me the results I want:

```
{0=>{"junior_collection"=>#<ActiveRecord::Relation [# ... ]>, "junior_columns"=>[ ... ]}, 1=>{"senior_collection"=>#<ActiveRecord::Relation [# ... ]>, "senior_columns"=>[ ... ]}}
```

The fact that I had to add the i variable makes me feel like this is not the ruby way to do this. But I looked at the docs and I didn't find a way to add an index to reduce, since I am already passing a hash into reduce. Is there another way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your way is probably good enough but you can avoid separately tracking the index by doing `.each.with_index.reduce(...) { |acc, ((k,v),i)| ... }`, like so:

```
h = {'a' => 'b', 'c' => 'd', 'e' => 'f'}
h.each.with_index.reduce('OK') do |acc, ((k, v), i)|
  puts "acc=#{acc}, k=#{k}, v=#{v}, i=#{i}"
  acc
end
# acc=OK, k=a, v=b, i=0
# acc=OK, k=c, v=d, i=1
# acc=OK, k=e, v=f, i=2
# => "OK"
```

Not sure if it's more Rubyish than your way =\

Comment: Readers: [Enumerable#each_with_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) could be used instead of `each.with_index`.  As both return enumerators, it really doesn't matter which is used. One small advantage of [Enumerator#with_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) (though not useful here) is that you can give `each_index` an argument equal to the starting point for the index (e.g., `with_index(1)`).